# Flutter: Fix "Argument type 'String' can't be assigned to 'List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, typeerror, argument-error

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter project:

```
 The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type
 'List<dynamic>'.
```

[image]

**This error appears within this code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ... other imports 

class MainController extends StatefulWidget {
  // ... existing code 
}

class Functionality extends State<MainController> {
  String _userName; // Likely source of the problem
  int userPoints = 0;
  Authenticate authenticate;

  // .. existing code

  Widget sideMenu(String titleName, IconData takeIcon) {
    // ... existing code 

    if (titleName == "Account") {
      List? takeInformation = authenticate.fetchDataToPreview(this._userName); 
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  AccountInformation(this._userName, takeInformation!))); // Potential null issue
    } 
    // ... rest of the function 
  }

  // ... rest of the code 
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

- I tried `final String _userName` but no luck, in this line:

  ```
  String _userName;
  ```
- Added "!" to `takeInformation` in the `Navigator.push` line, but the error persists

  ```
   AccountInformation(this._userName, takeInformation!)));
  ```

**Questions:**

1. How can I ensure that `authenticate.fetchDataToPreview()` indeed returns a `List<dynamic>`? Could there be a type mismatch causing this error?
2. Is there an issue with how I'm handling potential null values in the `takeInformation` list?

**Additional Context**

- I'm using Flutter with Android Studio.

Comment: which lines makes this error? can you show us the log?

Comment: Hello, I updated the post, so you can see the error

Comment: show the AccountInformation class. because, I think you defined list in that class and passing string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `AccountInformation` class, I guess you defined your user name as List like this:

```
final List username;
```

if you want to pass username as string type
change it to:

```
final String username;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PromoDoroClock the data type defined must be List but you are passing the _userName which is a string.